# "Отказано в доступе" при работе с процессами

Tags: c#, windows, безопасность, процесс

Обращение ко многим свойствам процессов (включая безобидные `StartTime`, `HasExited`) выдают это самое исключение. Много гуглил, но везде рекомендуют от имени администратора запускать программу, а это не помогает. Нет, пишу не вирус (на шарпе это уже было бы смешно), хочу искать зомби-процессы или всякую малварь. Как можно решить проблему? Поможет ли `WinAPI`?

Comment: >>хочу искать зомби-процессы или всякую малварь<< А почему бы не получить уровень привилегий антивируса? По поводу "зомби" - вы не перепутали ОС?

Comment: Не перепутал, я знаю, что они известны в Unix-системах, но прочтите этот (https://habr.com/company/infopulse/blog/349924/) пост. Про привилегии заинтриговали меня, можно подробнее?

Comment: Огромное спасибо за вашу ссылку на статью! Сами антивирусы в системе, насколько я знаю, имеют права выше дефолтного админа (+ запускаются от имени самой системы). Чем, непосредственно, помечаются такие программы (manifest, настройки в ОС, например, как это было сделано в win10 с браузером по умолчанию, или что то иное) - я не изучал. Есть подобные вопросы на MS: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/eebcac30-0389-4e12-873c-d92010b7750f/how-do-i-register-my-antivirus-program-in-windows-security-center-?forum=w7itprosecurity

Comment: Хм, процесс даже сложнее чем я думал: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/e1dd7668-0465-4200-a4bc-c38d091396ae/developing-an-antivirus-for-windows-7?forum=windowscompatibility

Comment: Что-то тут в кучу права администратора (т.е. членство в группе "Администраторы"), повышенные привилегии (т.е. разрешение UAC) и требования соответствия Microsoft Virus Initiative... Для получения информации о (чужих) процессах нужно первое и второе. Третье нужно в основном для того, чтобы программа воспринималась как антивирус самой ОС.

Comment: Спасибо за ваши ответы, буду читать, позже отпишусь.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы получить значения этих свойств для процесса, нужно иметь в отношении него право доступа PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION. Приложение всегда имеет это право в отношении других процессов того же пользователя, но для процессов других пользователей это право можно получить только при определенных условиях:

- Запускающий пользователь должен иметь привилегии отладки (SeDebugPrivilege). По умолчанию эти привилегии доступны группе "Администраторы", но могут быть назначены другим пользователям. Для простоты иногда говорят "права администратора".
- При включенном UAC нужно также повышение уровня привилегий (т.е., явное указание, что программа работает с правами администратора).

Если программа всегда должна запускаться с повышенными привилегиями, можно создать манифест и указать в нем это:

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">        
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />        
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
```

Для теста создадим простую программу для отображения времени работы всех процессов:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var processes = Process.GetProcesses();

            uint c_error = 0;

            foreach (Process pr in processes)
            {
                using (pr)
                {
                    Console.Write(pr.ProcessName.PadLeft(25));
                    try
                    {
                        Console.Write("\tRunning: " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(pr.StartTime).TotalHours.ToString("F3") + " hours ");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\t" + ex.Message);
                        c_error++;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        Console.Write("\tHasExited: " + pr.HasExited.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.Write("\t" + ex.Message);
                        c_error++;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Processes: {0}, Errors: {1}",
                processes.Length, c_error);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }    
}
```

Результаты запуска без повышенных привилегий:

```html
ConsoleApplication1.vshost      Running: 0,004 hours    HasExited: False
                  audiodg       Running: 0,003 hours    Отказано в доступе
                  browser       Running: 0,482 hours    HasExited: False
                  wininit       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
             aswidsagenta       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  browser       Running: 0,128 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                    csrss       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                      MDM       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  taskmgr       Running: 0,493 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                 igfxTray       Running: 0,501 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
    PresentationFontCache       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                   igfxHK       Running: 0,501 hours    HasExited: False
                WDExpress       Running: 0,224 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                   igfxEM       Running: 0,501 hours    HasExited: False
                      lsm       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                 AvastSvc       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  conhost       Running: 0,205 hours    HasExited: False
                 iusb3mon       Running: 0,504 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,213 hours    HasExited: False
                      LMS       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                 explorer       Running: 0,511 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                      dwm       Running: 0,511 hours    HasExited: False
                  AvastUI       Running: 0,504 hours    HasExited: False
           igfxCUIService       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                    csrss       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  spoolsv       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  browser       Running: 0,482 hours    HasExited: False
                  MSBuild       Running: 0,205 hours    HasExited: False
                    lsass       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  browser       Running: 0,481 hours    HasExited: False
                  conhost       Running: 0,000 hours    HasExited: False
                 services       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
       DiscSoftBusService       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
            SearchIndexer       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                 wmpnetwk       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
              jhi_service       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
          GISGKH Payments       Running: 0,505 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,475 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,478 hours    HasExited: False
                   DTLite       Running: 0,505 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
           service_update       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                 winlogon       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  browser       Running: 0,482 hours    HasExited: False
      ConsoleApplication1       Running: 0,000 hours    HasExited: False
           service_update       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  browser       Running: 0,310 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,477 hours    HasExited: False
                sqlwriter       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                     smss       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                 unsecapp       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                  svchost       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                   System       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе
                 taskhost       Running: 0,512 hours    HasExited: False
                     Idle       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе

Processes: 65, Errors: 75
```

С повышенными привилегиями:

```html
ConsoleApplication1.vshost      Running: 0,039 hours    HasExited: False
                  audiodg       Running: 0,038 hours    Отказано в доступе
                  browser       Running: 0,517 hours    HasExited: False
                  wininit       Running: 0,559 hours    HasExited: False
             aswidsagenta       Running: 0,549 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,163 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,556 hours    HasExited: False
                    csrss       Running: 0,559 hours    HasExited: False
                      MDM       Running: 0,554 hours    HasExited: False
                  taskmgr       Running: 0,528 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,554 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,553 hours    HasExited: False
                 igfxTray       Running: 0,536 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,557 hours    HasExited: False
    PresentationFontCache       Running: 0,537 hours    HasExited: False
                   igfxHK       Running: 0,536 hours    HasExited: False
                WDExpress       Running: 0,259 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,557 hours    HasExited: False
                   igfxEM       Running: 0,536 hours    HasExited: False
                      lsm       Running: 0,559 hours    HasExited: False
                 AvastSvc       Running: 0,556 hours    HasExited: False
                  dllhost       Running: 0,000 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,552 hours    HasExited: False
                  conhost       Running: 0,240 hours    HasExited: False
                 iusb3mon       Running: 0,539 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,247 hours    HasExited: False
                      LMS       Running: 0,519 hours    HasExited: False
                 explorer       Running: 0,546 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,553 hours    HasExited: False
                      dwm       Running: 0,546 hours    HasExited: False
                  AvastUI       Running: 0,539 hours    HasExited: False
           igfxCUIService       Running: 0,556 hours    HasExited: False
                    csrss       Running: 0,561 hours    HasExited: False
                  spoolsv       Running: 0,554 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,557 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,517 hours    HasExited: False
                  MSBuild       Running: 0,240 hours    HasExited: False
                    lsass       Running: 0,559 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,516 hours    HasExited: False
                 services       Running: 0,559 hours    HasExited: False
       DiscSoftBusService       Running: 0,538 hours    HasExited: False
      ConsoleApplication1       Running: 0,000 hours    HasExited: False
            SearchIndexer       Running: 0,536 hours    HasExited: False
                 wmpnetwk       Running: 0,535 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,557 hours    HasExited: False
              jhi_service       Running: 0,519 hours    HasExited: False
          GISGKH Payments       Running: 0,539 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,510 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,513 hours    HasExited: False
                   DTLite       Running: 0,540 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,554 hours    HasExited: False
           service_update       Running: 0,553 hours    HasExited: False
                 winlogon       Running: 0,559 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,517 hours    HasExited: False
                  dllhost       Running: 0,000 hours    HasExited: False
           service_update       Running: 0,553 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,345 hours    HasExited: False
                  browser       Running: 0,512 hours    HasExited: False
                sqlwriter       Running: 0,553 hours    HasExited: False
                     smss       Running: 0,562 hours    HasExited: False
                 unsecapp       Running: 0,541 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,557 hours    HasExited: False
                  svchost       Running: 0,557 hours    HasExited: False
                  conhost       Running: 0,000 hours    HasExited: False
                   System       Running: 0,562 hours    Отказано в доступе
                 taskhost       Running: 0,547 hours    HasExited: False
                     Idle       Отказано в доступе      Отказано в доступе

Processes: 67, Errors: 4
```

Как можно увидеть, при обычном запуске ошибку выдает на всех системных процессах, а при запуске с повышенными привилегиями - только на защищенных процессах (audiodg и System).